# update working in Robomongo and not from Meteor

Tags: meteor

This works and insert `{name: 'ok', color: '#ff0000'}` to the categories when using Robomongo

```
db.requirements.update({_id: 'kJBZp2gA8TgNX3z2j'}, {$addToSet: {categories: {name: 'ok', color: '#ff0000'}}})
```

It does not from Meteor.
It inserts an empty object `{}` into categories array

**EDIT**

After `SimpleSchema.debug = true;` I have this log:

> SimpleSchema.clean: filtered out value that would have affected key
>   "categories.$._id", which is not allowed by the schema

same for `name` and `color` thus inserting an empty object `{}`

The schema is:

```
  categories: {
    type: [{
      _id: {
        type: String
      },
      name: {
        type: String
      },
      color: {
        type: String
      }
    }],
    optional: true
  }
```

What would be the correct schema then ?

Comment: Did you have the cirrects allows?

Comment: The DB is updated (but wronly), so yes.

Comment: I traced the error to the use of SimpleSchema, still trying to understand (I have no error whatsoever).

Comment: check your server log & make sure you have `SimpleSchema.debug = true;` somewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much. Progress is made !

Answer (score 0):

I don't grasp all the differences, but here is the new schema that now works. Thanks Matt K for the debug option pointer.

```
  'categories.$._id': {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  'categories.$.name': {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  'categories.$.color': {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
```